# In rails4 form how to get the value of one field to assign to a session variable in the view itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, html, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to get the value of one form field in the form itself, to perform some ajax operations when the value of #product_form_item_unit_select changes.

I tried the below:

```
<%session[:item_id] = $('#product_form_item_unit_select)').value%>
```

But, the above will not work.Please help

Comment: If you want to set session to value of select list, you would have to pass selected value to the server as a params i.e as a data from jquery ajax call. Can you post code of your jquery ajax call.

Comment: $.ajax '/users/'+selectedProductId+'/users.json',
    type: 'GET'
    success: (data) ->
      ownerSelectBox = $('#itm_form_manu_select')

Comment: `$.ajax '/users/'+selectedProductId+'/users.json', type: 'GET', data: $('#product_form_item_unit_select)').value, success: (data) -> ownerSelectBox = $('#itm_form_manu_select')`

You can pass data as above to rails and inside controller action set the session. Also you can post as much as code possible in you question. This will help you to get answer faster.